# Is there any satirical political ideology?

Tags: ideology

Is there any political ideology created simply for humor? Or like a parody or for satire.
If not, then maybe a fictional political party invented for such purposes?

- There is fictional disease - Ligma
- There is a satirical religion - Pastafarianism
- There is a parody about what water is - Dihydrogen monoxide

I am looking for something similar in politics.

Hopefully the question is not inappropriate

Comment: Due to [Poe's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law), it's actually really hard to clearly tell satire and genuine extremism apart. It's difficult to tell if an apparently absurd political idea was created as satire but then taken seriously, or if it was created seriously by a deranged individual but was then adapted ironically by people finding it funny.

Comment: [Vermin Supreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermin_Supreme) might be an exception that proves the rule there, @Philipp :)

Comment: The answers to this questions are very useful but I accepted this question to be a duplicate. Not sure why two users asked for reopening it but I am not against it. If you tell me why it should be opened, I will ask that too

Answer (score 14):

The [Monster Raving Loony Party](https://www.omrlp.com/), is a satirical political party.  It has a platform that includes "fitting airbags to the stock exchange to be ready for the next crash" and "Summer Ice Lolly Allowance for OAPs if temperatures exceed 70F" (this latter is a parody of the Winter Fuel Allowance).

There are lots of other [similar parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_frivolous_political_parties), many of which claim to follow an ideology.

Just as with "Pastafarianism" there may be a serious aspect to the satire: These parties cause us to ask the question "on what basis do we judge a manifesto to be parody?" and "What makes a political party serious?".  They can also remind us that access to politics is for all.

Comment: Some of the less loony OMRLP policies [have ended up becoming law](https://www.mirror.co.uk/usvsth3m/7-monster-raving-loony-party-5644717) :-)

Comment: I also have to mention this guy from Denmark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Haugaard once elected he actually tried to implement his slogans and even managed to get Nutella in field rations

Comment: Satirical parties can also serve as an opportunity to cast "protest votes" in elections, allowing people to register their lack of respect for the political process as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

There have been many comic and satiric political parties and movements. One worth noting is the [Surprise Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gracie_Allen#Publicity_stunts) featuring Gracie Allen as candidate for the US Presidency. According to the linked Wikipedia article:

> In 1940, Allen announced she was running for president of the United States on the Surprise Party ticket. Burns and Allen did a cross-country whistlestop campaign tour on a private train, performing their live radio show in different cities. In one of her campaign speeches, Gracie said, "I don't know much about the Lend-Lease Bill, but if we owe it we should pay it." Another typical Gracie-ism on the campaign trail was: "Everybody knows a woman is better than a man when it comes to introducing bills into the house." The Surprise Party mascot was the kangaroo; the motto was "It's in the bag." As part of the gag, Allen (in reality, the Burns and Allen writers) published a book, *Gracie Allen for President*, which included photographs from their nationwide campaign tour and the Surprise Party convention. Allen received an endorsement from Harvard University. {*Citations omitted*}

Answer (score 1):

There are several terms describing governmental systems which were frequently used as polemic dysphemisms to criticize existing governments but were never *officially* implemented. Among those are:

- Hetaerocracy or [Pornocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornocracy): A political system where the official rulers are a puppet government controlled by their sexual partners.
- [Kleptocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleptocracy): Rulership by the most corrupt members of society
- [Kakistrocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakistocracy): Rulership by the most incompetent members of society. (not to be confused with [Khakistocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_dictatorship))
- [Ocholocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mob_rule): Also known as "Mob rule". A system where the government is forced to make irrational decisions because they are afraid of public disapproval.

Comment: Your link to Pornocracy doesn't seem to reflect the definition which you provide.

Comment: @NeilTarrant I believe it does. The term was coined to describe the [Saeculum obscurum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saeculum_obscurum), historical period where the popes were accused to be controlled by women they had affairs with. The literal translation of "Hetaerocracy" is "Rulership by courtisans", while "Pornocracy" translates to "Rulership by prostitutes", which basically describes the same thing, just with different connotations: The ruler is controlled by the woman he has sex with.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question "Is there any political ideology created simply for humor? "